# Apply padding-left to an li element in a toggable boostrap menu that ignores a checkmark icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I made a working toggable menu for an FAQ page. It works fine on desktop but on mobile devices not yet. The reason being that the content in the .panel section wraps around the checkmark when the title cannot be displayed on one single line. Basically what I am looking for is a way to apply padding-left to the title that applies to the entire title section. Right now the title on the second line ens up below the checkmark and I want to stop this from happening. Maybe there is a way to give padding-left to the h3 title while ignoring the checkmark icon? I'm having some problems phrasing this accurately so hopefully the bootply below will make it a bit more clear:

Have a look at the bootply below.

http://www.bootply.com/SWkBQnTDDB

```
    <div class="container">         
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <ul class="item-list" id="toggle-view">
                    <li>
                                        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title <span class="fa fa-caret-up"></span></h3>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>content content content content content</p>
                    </div>
                    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#toggle-view li').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');
    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
                    $(this).find('.fa-caret-up').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
                    $(this).find('.fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
    }     
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add p tags with the id panel-title to contain your title.

```
<div class="container">         
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <ul class="item-list" id="toggle-view">
                    <li>
                                        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                          <p id="panel-title">This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title This is the title</p> <span class="fa fa-caret-up"></span></h3>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>content content content content content</p>
                    </div>
                    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Gave the following CSS to .fa-check and #panel-title

```
.fa-check {
    max-width: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 10%;
  }

#panel-title { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for this simple solution.